# DHTMLX gantt - error TS6137: Cannot import type declaration files

Tags: angular, dhtmlx

This was working until yesterday, so I believe something changed either on typescript or dhtmlxgantt.

I am getting these errors on compilation:

`error TS2306: File 'projectPath/node_modules/@types/dhtmlxgantt/index.d.ts' is not a module.`

`src/app/shared/components/gantt/gantt.component.ts(11,17): error TS6137: Cannot import type declaration files. Consider importing 'dhtmlxgantt' instead of '@types/dhtmlxgantt'`

I also tried with their demo code and had the same error:
https://github.com/DHTMLX/angular2-gantt-demo

Has anyone experienced the same problem and can shed some light?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the type definitions of dhtmlx-gantt appears to be not compatible with typescript 2.9.1 (released yesterday https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/releases/tag/v2.9.1 )

The type definitions of dhtmlxGantt haven't been updated in a while, which is a main reason of the problem.

As a possible workaround for now, you can either downgrade the typescript in your project to 2.8.x (I've checked the build seems to be working on 2.8.4)

- `npm uninstall typescript`
- `npm install typescript@2.8.4`

or, specify the typescript version in package.json
`"typescript": "2.8.4",`

If downgrading is not an option, you can remove type definitions of dhtmlx gantt and declare gantt instance manually:
`declare let gantt: any;`

obviously, you'll lose the type info, but it still seems to be better than the project that won't compile

### UPDATE

Type definitions were updated by this [pull request](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/30311), kudos to https://github.com/duayres.

Thus, this problem should be fixed now

Comment: Would be great to get it fixed though.